# How to setup a pre-build MariaDB Docker image using CircleCI 2.0

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I am trying to setup a MariaDB in my CircleCI 2.0 build but I am having problems to find a documentation how to configure the MariaDB Docker container. Here is what I did so far.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:9-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      - image: circleci/mariadb:10.3.4-ram
        environment:
          MARIADB_USER: username
          MARIADB_PASSWORD: pwd
          MARIADB_DB: test-db
```

I would like to define:

- Database name
- Database user
- Database user password

Then I would like to create a database called `test-db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CircleCI MariaDB Docker image is based on the Docker Library image which you can find here, with instructions: https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/

In your case its

```
  - image: circleci/mariadb:10.3.4-ram
    environment:
       - MYSQL_DATABASE: test-db
       - MYSQL_USER: username
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
```

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI